# HTML p line breaks (repost of a repost)

Tags: html, css, layout

I know this question has been asked many times before, but never an answer that helps me in my situation.

I have a `<p>` with a `<ul>` underneath it. There is whitespace between the paragraph and the list. I don't want this but can't get rid of it.

I've applied the most straight-forward solution but it doesn't work in my page.

This is what it should be: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EsFqd
And this is what I get with the same css as shown in codepen:
[image]

Who can help me out?

As requested, HTML:

```
<article id="overzicht"
         style="<% if (browser.contains("Chrome") || browser.contains("MSIE")) {%>margin-right: 45px;<%}%>">
    <header>
        <h2>Overzicht</h2>
    </header>
    <div id="lijsten" data-collapse="persist">
        <p class="open">Groepen</p>
        <ul>
            <% try {
                while (bands.next()) { %>
            <li><%= bands.getString("band_naam") %></li>
            <li><%= bands.getString("pod_omschr") %></li>
            <%  }
               } catch (Exception e) { %>
            <li>Nog geen groepen</li>
            <% }%>
        </ul>
        <p>Campings</p>
        <ul>
            <% try {
                while (campings.next()) { %>
            <li><%= campings.getString("camp_adres") %></li>
            <li><%= campings.getString("camp_cap") %></li>
            <%  }
               } catch (Exception e) { %>
            <li>Nog geen campings</li>
            <% }%>
        </ul>
        <p>Tickets</p>
        <ul>
            <% try {
                while (tickets.next()) { %>
            <li><%= tickets.getString("typ_omschr") %></li>
            <li><%= tickets.getString("typ_prijs") %></li>
            <%  }
               } catch (Exception e) { %>
            <li>Nog geen tickets</li>
            <% }%>
        </ul>
    </div>
</article>
```

and full CSS:

```
article[id="details"] {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
p {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
    background-color: green;
}

ul {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 200, 0.2);
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
    border-top: none;
}
li {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: -30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin-left: -40px;
    padding-left: -40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
li:first-child {
    padding-top: 3px;
}
```

Comment: The link to what it should be has been edited. I copied the wrong link. This is where you'll find an example of what it should be and the picture in this post is what I have: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EsFqd

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Why and how should I reset?

Comment: It's tough to debug a picture.  And a link to what it "should be" doesn't help either.  Can you share the code that is actually producing the problem?

Comment: Alright, I'll add the full html I am using.
But what you find in codepen (the link) is what I'm using in my project

Comment: By the way, you cannot have negative padding.

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML instead of the ASP?

Comment: Writing “I know this question has been asked many times before, but never an answer that helps me in my situation” means that you intentionally post a question that is a duplicate of many questions. You do not however identify which questions, so this is probably best closed as “not a real question”.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I've mentioned before that I've seen many solutions but never the one I was looking for. You should know that this question has some unique twist to it. This is a place for learning isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the CSS on your actual site is the same as in CodePen, it sounds like you need a reset, or have conflicting CSS.

Maybe try adding `margin: 0 !important;` to see if that sorts the problem for you. If so there's probably some other styles being applied that are more specific than your `ul` selector.

Like others have said though, seeing your actual CSS would make troubleshooting a LOT easier.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you...
the !important did the job. I'm not very good yet in finding a conflict in a hay stack :)

Comment: No problem. The !important isn't really a great solution though, it just proves that you have conflicting CSS. You either need a proper CSS reset, or you have a more specific selector eg: `.sidebar ul` (or something) that is more specific than your `ul` selector. Go through your CSS to check for something that could be over-riding your style (Y)

Answer (score 1):

You most likely need to use a css reset. This will reset all the default browser (user agent) html styling to a consistent baseline. Codepen is most likely using such a reset and thus the difference in your code from theirs.

Add the css for Eric Meyers reset style sheet at the top of your css. You can find it here http://www.cssreset.com/. Reload your page and see if it removes the spacing.

Edit: Avoid using !important because it will potentially override your other margin styles in your application. This can cause lots of headaches in the long run. Go with a css reset or figure out why the margin is being applied and override that style with less forceful css specificity.

Comment: My problem is fixed, but i'll try you method too and see if it helps

Comment: I'd recommend NOT using !important. You can read about css specificity here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/ “If you’re having specificity issues, there’s some quick ways to solve it. First, avoid !important.” “The !important declaration overrides normal declarations, but is unstructured and rarely required in an author’s style sheet.”

Comment: I agree, `!important` wasn't a solution to the problem. It just proves that you either need a CSS reset, or have another CSS selector over-riding your `ul` selector. You need to firstly go through your CSS to make sure there are no conflicting selectors. If you have no luck with that, then try a CSS reset as suggested here.

Comment: Gotcha. Good trouble shooting.

Answer (score 0):

I know `!important` seemed to fix your problem. But for now remove it and try adding:

```
body, * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

to the top of your CSS file to see if that fixes it. If not, maybe try the CSS reset mentioned in @mikecan's answer.